# -CDI deployment failure- maven project on NetBeans 8.1

Tags: netbeans-8, mahout-recommender

I create a maven web application on Netbeans IDE 8.1.Then, i add some ressources(js,css,...) and a web page index.html

Also i add these dependencies to pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-integration</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the error:

```
Grave:   Exception while loading the app
    Grave:   Undeployment failed for context /SecondAppPfa
    Grave:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default
      at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)
      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager.<init>(ServiceManager.java:0)
    org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default
      at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)
      at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager.<init>(ServiceManager.java:0)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

just add beans.xml file under META-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```